# Symfony: datetime property string contraint violation

Tags: symfony, constraints, postman

I am currently learning how to use the Symfony framework. The project that I'm working on is a Web API for a blog application.

Now I have created the necessary entities, provided data into it, set JWT Tokens, etc.. 
The next step was to automatically set an author (which is currently authorized with the token) to a written blog post. I've added some constraints and other annotations, but when I now use Postman to "POST" a new blog onto the DB it gives me the following error:

[image: Postman constraint error]

```
{
   "title": "Latest Blog Post!",
   "published": "2020-08-02 17:00:00",
   "content": "This the contentof the latest blog post!",
   "slug": "latest-blog-post"
}
```

Now, the thing is that the property "published" is of type datetime:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\BlogPostRepository")
* @ApiResource(
*     itemOperations={"get"},
*     collectionOperations={
*         "get",
*         "post"={
*             "access_control"="is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')"
*         }
*     }
* )
*/
 class BlogPost
 {
         /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
         * @Assert\NotBlank()
         * @Assert\DateTime()
         */
         private $published;


        public function getPublished(): ?\DateTimeInterface
        {
            return $this->published;
        }

        public function setPublished(\DateTimeInterface $published): self
        {
            $this->published = $published;

            return $this;
        }
 }
```

What am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted: `@Assert\DateTime()` and everything worked again properly.